# NodeJS function cooldown

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I've recently been getting indo Node, and I'm curious if anybody has a better way to set a "global cooldown" on their functions (similar to a flood protection system). I feel like what I've written **possibly** can't be the most efficient way to go. Here's what I got so far:

```
var onCooldown = false;

function foo() {
  if (onCooldown) return;

  else {
    // do stuff;

    onCooldown = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      onCooldown = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

What it does (or should do): when function `foo` is called, it checks if onCooldown is true or false. If it's true, it returns. If it's false, it does its stuff, then sets the onCooldown back to true for 5 seconds. This means that the function can be called, but wont respond, for 5 seconds, hence 'cooldown'.

Since I'm new, I'm not sure how to execute this, but I think I know what the optimal would be. With the current code, function foo could be called repeatedly even when on cooldown (which might affect performance?), so if it's possible to make the function not interactable during those 5 seconds, that would probably be optimal. Again, I'm not sure how to do this, that's why I'm asking.

There's probably a npm out there that does it, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I tried lodash's throttle, but it didn't work the way I expected it to (might've just configured it wrong).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is "debounce" this function, in which case there are myriad solutions out there for doing this. Lodash's `_.debounce` is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more portable solution, you should give Lodash's [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) a look.

The first argument to `debounce` is the function you want to debounce. The second argument is the number of milliseconds to debounce your function for. `debounce` returns the debounced function.

Using your code, you would use it like so:

```
function foo() { 
    // do stuff 
}

let debouncedFoo = _.debounce(foo, 5000); // debounce for 5 seconds

debouncedFoo(); // call it repeatedly
```